# How to find the limit with limit on variable in power?

Tags: limits

I was reading the paper [Quantum Computational Complexity in the Presence of Closed Timelike Curves](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0309189v3.pdf) and I am unable to prove a limit in it:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}(1-\frac{s}{2^{n-1}})^{x}=0 \;\;\;where  \;\;\; 0< s < 2^{n}$$

Comment: $0<\frac{s}{2^{n-1}}<2$ assuming $n$ is positive

Comment: @Klobbbyyy thanks got it :)yes n is a positive integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(1-\frac{s}{2^{n-1}}\right)^{x}=0, \quad0< s < 2^{n}$$

As $0<s<2^n$, $\displaystyle \frac{s}{2^{n-1}}\in(0,2)$, So $\displaystyle 1-\frac{s}{2^{n-1}}\in(-1,1)$, or $\displaystyle \left|1-\frac{s}{2^{n-1}}\right|<1$, As $\lim_{x\to\infty}k=0,|k|<1$, the rest remains understood.